# Dependency Injection with dagger2 in Android

Tags: android, dagger-2

I am learining to use Dagger 2 in Android at the moment. I think I understand the idea of how it works, but I have some doubts about a few details. In various tutorials about Dagger 2 in Android I've seen the use of `AndroidInjector`. It looks great but I have some questions about it.

1. Application class `onCreate` is creating a component and that component is injecting all activities and fragments. Is this happening at the start of the application or when the specific activity or fragment is created?
2. What I don't like that in this approach is that when I would have 100 activities and each activity would have 2 fragments then in ActivityModule I would have to write 100 times :

   `@ContributesAndroidInjector abstract fun contributeMyActivity(): MyActivity`

   And again same thing 200 times for fragments. It's a lot of boilerplate code. Am I right or am I missing something here? Is there some other better approach for this?
3. When application component is injecting all activities then there is no need for other components? Is it just this one big one created at the start of the application? Are there some situations when other components could be needed?

Answer (score 0):

Dagger2 Android is little different from Standard Dagger2 when it comes to custom scoping and subComponents
Dagger2 android provides you little leverage of not worrying about subComponent. The thing you are talking about is actually a subComponent. And Your Questions:

> 1.Application class onCreate is creating a component and that component is injecting all activities and fragments. Is this happening at the start of the application or when the specific activity or fragment is created?

**Answer**: Yes, It depends what else you've in that component how many activities and how many fragments and which activity/fragment is you starter activity/fragment and which activity is directly associate with your that application level component and yes application inject/init just for once as long as application is not destroyed.

> 2.What I don't like that in this approach is that when I would have 100 activities and each activity would have 2 fragments then in ActivityModule I would have to write 100 times :
>
> @ContributesAndroidInjector abstract fun contributeMyActivity(): MyActivity
> And again same thing 200 times for fragments. It's a lot of boilerplate code. Am I right or am I missing something here? Is there some other better approach for this?

**Answer**: The better way to do this is to provide subComponent for each activity and you don't need to worry about what 199th activity would be doing because your 199th activity is associate with that 199th component and 199th component only connected to appComponent not the other subComponent and that one subComponent is associate with your that one activity and that one activity is for that fragment or two fragments and yeah don't forget to scope each component accordingly and you don't worry about appComponent and subComponent it's like inheritence *Child can access everthing that parent has.*

> 3.When application component is injecting all activities then there is no need for other components?

**Answer**: NO!!
You have 200 activities? You can make 200 components for each activity and each component will be connected to Application level component to access the app level dependency/object graph
Now i'm gonna ask simple question..
Who creates 200 activities?

Android team suggested to use dagger2 And they admitted that it's steep learning curve but they still wants devs to use dagger2 and they are more focusing on standard dagger2 rather than android dagger2.
This is the disadvantage of dagger android it forces use to couple you activity with androidContributeInjector() it doesn't give that freehand to play around more you want with component but the standard dagger2 does that.. Personally i was using dagger2-Android but i switched to standard-Dagger2 and now its provides full control over the component or subComponents..

Here is what you need Actually
https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/dagger-android